# vkQueuePresentKHR takes 250 milliseconds on Android

Tags: android, c++, vulkan

A few weeks ago I decided to try and port my then Windows-only game engine to Android. After some twiddling, I got it working, and my test scene showed up on my Android phone, albeit with very poor performance. Around 2 FPS. I decided to do a pass and optimize my render passes and got it up to around 5 FPS, which still is horrible performance. After this I decided to go in hard and see how long each function took in my Vulkan backend, and subsequently reached the point where I found the offender - vkQueuePresentKHR. It takes around 250 milliseconds, which is obviously too long. Anyone has any ideas on what might be wrong, or has had similar problems? I have tried changing between the different present modes and surface formats with no success.

Comment: I've got to ask. Are you testing an unoptimized debug build or an optimized release build? (Default is usually unoptimized debug build unless you do something to change that and enabling optimizations often makes a *huge* difference)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hi Jesper, thanks for answering. I've tried using different optimization flags (-O2 -O3 -Os) to enable compiler optimizations, but maybe you're talking about a different thing?

Comment: That's what I was talking about. What differences did you observe (if any)?

Comment: You can use systrace (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/systrace) to see where vkQueuePresentKHR is spending its time. If you were able to speed it up from 2fps to 5fps by optimizing your rendering code, I'd still check how long your command buffers are taking to execute, using queue submission fences or timestamp queries. It may be that you're still really limited by GPU execution time rather than vkQueuePresentKHR (though in that case I'd expect it to be vkAcquireNextImageKHR that ends up blocking, not vkQueuePresentKHR).